# Custom props in a Button react component allowed in a specific defined interface

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have this code:

```
interface ICustomProps {
    'data-event-name': AllowedEvents;
    'data-event-to': string;
}

interface IButton {
    type?: ButtonTypes;
    icon?: string;
    iconPosition?: string;
    size?: ButtonSizes;
    hide?: boolean;
    onClick?(event?: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>): void;
    disabled?: boolean;
    text?: string;
    event?: React.HTMLProps<HTMLButtonElement> | ICustomProps;
    title?: string;
    iconSize?: IconSizes;
    iconColor?: IconColor;
    style?: React.CSSProperties;
    className?: string;
    children?: React.ReactNode;
}
```

My expectations were that I couldn't use any props in that Button but these declared. So, any HTMLButtonElement prop and also the defined ones, such as "title" or "icon".

But I have two problems:

1. When I call this component I was expecting the list of allowed values for the prop "data-event-name", but the IDE didn't show them
2. If I would write any random prop, typescript compiler should throw an error, but it doesn't. So I can call this component with random prop such as `foo-prop="blah"` without receiving any error. I guess is something about props with "-"

P.S.

```
type AllowedEvents = typeof allEvents[number];
```

where allEvents is an array of strings

[here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoctCAOwGd4UAbJgUQDckaY64BeOAG18STtwCM%20ADQFRXGACZpssTADM%20ALoVyMAJ5gkcAIIsIAdyQATDvN4D9hiJjjM2quoJoBXEACMkKG1KYG5AzHQjAEkAYW8GXAAFHDBeAG9yOCyCKxQYFABaOW4CmhQQJHwALhMzSxsPCmycvMLimAKYCGq4BihQgHMKAF8QsKgItGiAIW8YLpo4DObgahoAfhq%20wabs1dpEiDpgGGBaTd6YfpohzOyAC2ArJAu-CAgmVBpdrNoYplWAGt1gAKdoXZDoGAAOgAshB4khbNwADwACQAKrCADKsT4VbgAPgAlDV2BAnj84FZgHQUH5PlZXu9PihvncsjAkAAPGAXbY3KngmqQjDQzE45IQVLorHY2bzWh4pAEmCEuAAHzgsXiXRAUtSVNOME%20-KuOw5lz0ppFxBhMQAyg6DYFTkg6FS0EwUHQ6AA5covLbmwWWtCPJhWIgbW1Q6GimB%20iDPEaUNYMOAKhb8OAgtJwdpwYY1KJZ2jE-jq5bZdPwCpQAbWA32JZwaHtwvDHTNIgwbxQRYgy3NFF%20ObZtLt6H1xtWZvDOAAekJluJ5FGVFoGYx7pgMVwkBo8hzIIrfCrlt7-cHw%20yKLLi1y%20SKqlKgb4ACIaBAOjzaacbhfeQPzgb9f25f9BgKMAUgKcwTnuApcjoe4%20DSK5vCQBcwNYCCGEGA00PEBdl1XEYgA) a reproducible case

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (in the form of a link to a [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) would be ideal).

Comment: sorry, edited with a link

Answer (score 0):

I'll start with some context: here is a summary from the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#all-supported-html-attributes) about HTML attribute support. (Please read the docs page to view the full list of *camelCased* attributes):

> As of React 16, any standard [or custom](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/08/dom-attributes-in-react-16.html) DOM attributes are fully supported.
>
> React has always provided a JavaScript-centric API to the DOM. Since React components often take both custom and DOM-related props, React uses the `camelCase` convention just like the DOM APIs:
>
> ```js
> <div tabIndex={-1} />      // Just like node.tabIndex DOM API
> <div className="Button" /> // Just like node.className DOM API
> <input readOnly={true} />  // Just like node.readOnly DOM API
> ```
>
> These props work similarly to the corresponding HTML attributes, with the exception of the special cases documented above.
>
> ...
>
> You may also use custom attributes as long as they’re fully lowercase.

With that in mind, let's get into the details of your question:

---

### Your `AllowedEvents` type

Currently you have this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgGwQUQG4FMxQjAvDAbQHJ0MsBGIgGhhLKgCZrbTMoBmIgXQG4YB6fjGgAnAJZgA5gS4AoKAE8ADuhgBBJCADu6ACZo2OfIpUgAZvCQGsEAmACuAWwBG6EbwFDREyUA)

```ts
const allEvents = ['event1', 'event2', 'event3']; // string[]
type AllowedEvents = typeof allEvents[number]; // string
```

`allEvents` is inferred as `string[]` by the compiler, so `AllowedEvents` is `string`. This isn't what you wanted, but you can get the result that you want by telling the compiler to use [literal inference using `as const`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-inference), like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgGwQUQG4FMxQjAvDAbQHJ0MsBGIgGhhLKgCZrbTMoBmIgXXh1EigBuGAHoRMAE7o4AE3AIAnoQBErCspqr6DDTC1t2yrgCgoCgA7oYAQSQgA7uhlo2OfGcsgAZvCQusEARgAK4AtgBG6BJcwmJ6alDkyjAAPvHayWn6WIZAA)

```ts
const allEvents = ['event1', 'event2', 'event3'] as const; // readonly ["event1", "event2", "event3"]
type AllowedEvents = typeof allEvents[number]; // "event1" | "event2" | "event3"
```

Now, `AllowedEvents` is one of those string literals!

---

### Your `IButton['event']` type

When you need to determine a type used by an import, you can use IntelliSense to discover it. In this case, you can create a bare JSX `<button>` and hover it to see the type of its props:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwCYFMBmBDArgG3hgZzgCUUMBjGAXzjSghDgHIozKmBuAKC-IgDsC8AEZYYMAXAC8cABQAeUeIEA+eQHolE-ioCU3IA)

[image: IntelliSense]

The type that you need is: `React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>`.

I think you want to *merge* this with your `ICustomProps` interface, but right now you're creating a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#unions), which means x OR y:

```ts
event?: ICustomProps | React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>;
```

Instead, you want an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#intersections) to create x AND y, like this:

```ts
event?: ICustomProps & React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>;
```

---

Similar to the `<button>` props, you can discover the inferred type for its `onClick` attribute using IntelliSense: it's `React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>`. If you want it to be more generic (for another type of element in your actual component), you can use `React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLElement>`.

---

### Putting it all together

> I renamed a few things, and removed the extra properties that should be taken care of by the HTML button attributes:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwCYFMBmBDArgG3hgZzgCUUMBjGAXzjSghDgHIozKmBuAKC-IgDsC+HDgCiANxT8YRALxwA2kxSTpARiYAaZiqkwATFp2qYAZiYBdOITh9BMbjACeYFHACCIiAHcUSCXpycM6uEGjWIgHSBAr8WCAARihQFtxcwNLJmORuAMJYQgzuMDBQwAlYMChECFxwzEgYMBgAtLrSLfwYIChMAFweXr7+JgTc9UyNzW0mLTAQ-XBCZfwA5txUPBlVUNluAEKV8-wACvRgNXXWJWUVVQQA-AP5hSDFpeWV1XAAZCRsMAAdAARFDNYA4PwACQAKgBZAAyZwgFwAPKQKEDDiUBLDEe9bl8CKi8QjscdRJCetIAHzaUnkgSUlDUmA08ZwYB2J5LD5rDlcgQnCAEYAwYACHnLDLrK4AC2AqB5CQgEEhGH4HKqAA8YFK+bL6uQFTgkKx+DyMZRAVaYAA5CCoDY8OxCOCM-hweQACjA5wIAw9yIuAEovTTEFdWDAsFBPd7UXdjohAam-SiCICmh87tUqDSEOmLoCddRUQB6JMCGkhjZpV3wGHVGC5BiQfh6L1wb1h2QR2r1aOx+NXeqoj2j+rXHNE2QIAdTxeTJqtdowTrdXoDJj8CDrlDa4BCGUzPRGcvl4IuPy2ArzRjZwlVbQZPhQViUODiDA4LBuEIoJOS67vuh7HmsLRFi03hinKLSNAQcqLKUf7aBecBYPwADWu7eJ65B3gw05Pig2i2pyRAQFhcAwTAcrBAqBBAVOIGiGB4prMGAxqGhl6YThPj4YRD43J8z7-JiFFwFRNGwQxR7MfUQhOJCc5gBgSBIDK24AAyAgArKwIBMFQvESdauQAMqWcGyTit8AA+GH8KgaAZH4zFUJsi71AqqBzpgOAECg3k+aWsgAERwk4cBVvwEWTuWNJXLWXBUNwQA)

```ts
import {default as React} from 'react';

const allEvents = ['event1', 'event2', 'event3'] as const;
type AllowedEvents = typeof allEvents[number];

interface CustomAttributes {
  'data-event-name': AllowedEvents;
  'data-event-to': string;
}

interface ButtonProps {
  attributes?: CustomAttributes & React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>;
  icon?: string;
  iconPosition?: string;
  hide?: boolean;
  text?: string;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}

const Button = (props: ButtonProps) => {
  return (<button {...props.attributes}>{props.text}</button>);
};

const TestComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Button
      attributes={{
        'data-event-name': 'not-existing-event', // typed custom attribute, incorrect value type
        'not-existing-prop-with-dash': true, // unknown custom attribute, React is ok with this
        notExistingProp: 1, // unknown custom attribute, React is ok with this
        style={padding: '0.5rem'}, // React.CSSProperties | undefined
      }}
      hide={false}
      text="My button"
    />
  );
};
```